# Moya build error

Tags: swift3, moya

Added a pod file from `Moya`, but came up with a build time error. Unconvinced, created a new project, set up pod and added `Moya` and installed the pod. Came up the same set of build time compiler errors. I see no issues opened in issues of `Moya` GitHub repo. Using XCode 8.2.1 and swift 3 if it helps.[image: Screenshot of the build time compiler error]

Comment: seems swift 3 errors to me I think you need an swift 3 updated framework.

Comment: i have the same issue as well !

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to fix this problem:

1. Build settings -> search swift, choice use legacy swift language
   version Toggled no to yes -> build.
2. You will get more error. Back
3. toggled yes to no. build -> success!